# visudo + read access to file from non root user

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, sudo, user-permissions

how to access  file by visudo from non root user , or other option

for example

when we change user to hdfs
and from user hdfs we want to print the file - **file.cfg** we get Permission denied

how to configure the visudo in order to get read access from user - hdfs ( and without to use sudo command )

```
# su hdfs
$ whoami
hdfs
$ pwd
/opt/home/security
$ cat file.cfg
cat: sec.cfg: Permission denied

$ ls -ltr
```

file is ended with dot:

```
-rwxr-----. 1 root root   sec.cfg
```

expected output

```
# su hdfs
$ pwd
/opt/home/security
cat file.cfg

app_q 384273462 pass BHYVF^GTYR&GV@yhgb2yr
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your file permissions unless user *hdfs* is in group *root*.

Add read permission to *others* with `chmod 0744 /opt/home/security/file.cfg` or add your user to group *root*.